# How to deserialize xml into list in c#

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization, deserialization

I want to deserealize this XML in nested classes containing attributes and lists:

```xml
<BetradarLiveOdds timestamp="1630916055900" status="meta">
    <Match active="0" booked="0" matchid="22546" status="ended">
        <MatchInfo>
            <DateOfMatch>16309114325</DateOfMatch>
            <Sport id="32">Bos</Sport>
            <Category id="266">Interonal</Category>
            <Tournament id="99000526">Grd Pix 221</Tournament>
            <HomeTeam id="45179">Mrk Roal</HomeTeam>
            <AwayTeam id="41325">Mathew Whrs</AwayTeam>
            <TvChannels />
        </MatchInfo>
        <Translation>
            <Sport id="32">
                <Name lang="en">Bols</Name>
                <Name lang="it">Bols</Name>
            </Sport>
            <Category id="266">
                <Name lang="en">Interonal</Name>
                <Name lang="it">Internanale</Name>
            </Category>
            <Tournament id="99000526">
                <Name lang="en">Grand Prix 2021</Name>
                <Name lang="it">Grand Prix 2021</Name>
            </Tournament>
            <HomeTeam id="45179">
                <Name lang="en">Mark Royal</Name>
                <Name lang="it">Mark Royal</Name>
            </HomeTeam>
            <AwayTeam id="41325">
                <Name lang="en">Matthew Whyers</Name>
                <Name lang="it">Matthew Whyers</Name>
            </AwayTeam>
        </Translation>
    </Match>
</BetradarLiveOdds>
```

I have created multiple classes serializable as these:

```
[Serializable()]
public class BetradarLiveOdds
{
    [XmlAttribute("timestamp")]
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("match")]
    public List<Match> Matchs { get; set; } 
}

[Serializable()]
public class Match
{
    [XmlAttribute("active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("booked")]
    public bool Booked { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("matchid")]
    public Int32 MatchId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("matchinfo")]
    public MatchInfo MatchInfo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("translation")]
    public List<Translation> Translations { get; set; } 
}
```

And other little classes(sport,tournament,hometeam...).

I try: When i try to deserialize:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BetradarLiveOdds));
    BetradarLiveOdds bet;

    FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\src\\bet2020\\RD_Live_Parsing\\meta\\hi.xml", FileMode.Open);
    bet = (BetradarLiveOdds)serializer.Deserialize(fs);

    serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, bet);
}
```

`BetradarLiveOdds` print ok but match is empty.
Does anyone know how to modify the classes or the main so that it works. How can I deserealize the file?

Comment: Serialize the classes you have. If the XML doesn't match the XML you're trying to deserialize, you know where the issue is.

Comment: I think the issue is in the "BetradarLiveOdds" but i don t know how resolve it

Comment: In your classes you've used `List`, but the XML doesn't show any repetition (such as multiple `Match`).

Comment: because the program should work even in case of xml with more matches.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the case-sensitivity. `[XmlArrayItem("match")]` should be `[XmlArrayItem("Match")]`.

Comment: when i try to add manually an object with "bet.Matchs.Add(new Match() { MatchId = 1234 });  it returns me the error "Reference to an object not set to an object instance"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using the following class definitions then your deserializer + serializer code will work fine with single or multiple `<Match>` nodes:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class BetradarLiveOdds
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Match[] Match { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

- I have omitted all those attributes, which are unnecessary
- `XmlSerializer` can work with `List<Match>` as well if you need a list rather than an array

```
public class Match
{
    public MatchInfo MatchInfo { get; set; }
    public Translation Translation { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "active")]
    public string Active { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "booked")]
    public string Booked { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "matchid")]
    public string Matchid { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class MatchInfo
{
    public string DateOfMatch { get; set; }
    public Common Sport { get; set; }
    public Common Category { get; set; }
    public Common Tournament { get; set; }
    public Common HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public Common AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public string TvChannels { get; set; }
}
```

- I've introduced a `Common` class which can be used in `MatchInfo` and in `Translation`
- In case of `MatchInfo` the `Name` collections will be empty (an initialized list with 0 element)

  - If that's undesirable then you can introduce yet another class which will not contain the `Name` property

```
public class Translation
{
    public Common Sport { get; set; }
    public Common Category { get; set; }
    public Common Tournament { get; set; }
    public Common HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public Common AwayTeam { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Common
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Name> Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Name
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang")]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```